# fragment shared elements transition not working

Tags: java, android

I have an activity and it contains three fragment. 
Then, I used viewpager adapter to create a fragment.
There is something curious about it.

Is it possible to use shared elements transition in fragment inside activity?
shared elements trasition only use activity to activity and fragment to fragment?

I would like to call activity or activityDialog at fragment. but not working..
How can I do.

Activity

```
private List<Fragment> getPagerAdapterItems() {

    if (fragments.size() == 0) {

        FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA ();
        fragments.add(fragmentA);

        FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB ();
        fragments.add(fragmentB);

        FragmentC fragmentC = new FragmentC ();
        fragments.add(fragmentC);
    }

    return fragments;
}

private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return getPagerAdapterItems().get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return getPagerAdapterItems().size();
    }
}
```

Fragment A inside Activity

```
@OnClick(R.id.ly_wheather)
void onClick() {
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), iv_img, "img");
    getActivity().startActivity(ActivityDialog.getIntent(getContext()), options.toBundle());
}
```

ActivityDialog

```
public static Intent getIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityDialog.class);
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: It's possible, but without any of your code, it's hard to tell where it's not working. Could you please update your original post to include what you have so far? Thanks

Comment: @Drew I added code..

Comment: I completed it. makeSceneTransitionAnimation's third parameter wasn't equal to TransitionName.